# I have written a couple of Pythonscripts to take links from each wiki page and print a 2 sentence summary about it

Tags: python, wikipedia

The script 1 works fine giving me the file with the links required.

I get results like this after running script 1 which i store in a textfile

/wiki/Relationship_(disambiguation)
/wiki/Social_science
/wiki/Agency_(sociology)
/wiki/Social_structure

In script 2 I often come across the error "Page id "xxxxxx" does not match any pages. Try another id!
Why is wiki not able to find these pages.
My aim is to find as many articles as possible from the links generated in first script , I want to skip only a few articles

In rare cases is there a way to skip over such error messages and just extract next article, how can this be done ?

Script 1

```
enter code here
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

##paste here the link you want to open or the main wiki page 
html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_relation")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

##change the name of the text file accordinly
t = open("linkedwords.txt", 'w')

# final regex string returns all links that start
#with /wiki/ and after that do not contain    any colons 
for link in bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll( "a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki 
/)((?!:).)*$") ):
    if 'href' in link.attrs: 
        t.write(str(link.attrs['href']) + "\n")

t.close()
```

Script 2

```
import wikipedia
import re 
# import any wikipedia article
wikipedia.set_lang("en")  

##importing wikipedia articles from the files
with open("linkedwords.txt") as f:
   word = f.read().splitlines()

#need to solve raise DisambiguationError(getattr
#wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: 

for i in word:
   wiki =  wikipedia.summary(i, sentences= 2)
   text = wiki
   text = re.sub(r'==.*?==+', '', text)
   text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
   file1 = open("theme.txt","a") 
   file1.writelines('\n') 
   file1.writelines(i) 
   file1.writelines('\n') 
   file1.writelines(text) 
   file1.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps a try/except block.

Answer (score 0):

1. `wikipedia.summary()` requires a page title without the /wiki/ part. So change the second last line of script 1 to the following:

   ```
   t.write(str(link.attrs['href'][6:]) + "\n")
   ```

   linkedwords.txt will then only contain page names without the /wiki/ prefix.
2. `wikipedia.summary()` is not able to produce a summary for disambiguation pages, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship. To catch these errors, put the function into a try/except block:

   ```
    try:
        wiki =  wikipedia.summary(i, sentences= 2)
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError:
        print('error: no summary for disambiguation page')
        continue
   ```
3. In case you run python3 on Windows, you need to add `encoding="utf-8"` when opening the theme.txt file:

   ```
   file1 = open("theme.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
   ```